# How to Copy Files Without Overwriting Any Files in Bash Script

Tags: bash, find, overwrite, cp

I am trying to write a script that finds all my files that are .jpg, and copies them do a new directory. It currently looks like this:

```
find ~/Pictures -iname \*.jpg -exec cp {} ...newDirectory \;
```

The problem is that some of my older files have the same name as newer files, when the IMG_#### reset back to 0001 and started counting again.

Is there a way to find the .jpgs and copy without overwriting the files? Ideally giving them a new name in the process.

EDIT

I ended up learning about rsync, which in its own way does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Use `-n` parameter for `cp`, that means: do not overwrite an existing file.

To prevent identical names, you could just name all of them unique.
Example:

```
$ touch screenshot.jpg
$ cp screenshot.jpg screenshot-$(date "+%s").jpg
```

So basically, mass rename the new files you want to copy to the same name+date.
That will make them different from what's already there, sice the older ones are unnamed or (if you repeat this later) will have different dates.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. When I put this command into the find function, it only executes the copying/name change on one of the files. Any ideas why?
'find ~/Desktop/pic_folder/ -iname \*.jpg -exec cp {} ~/Desktop/new_folder/name-$(date "+%s").jpg \;'

Comment: How can I use this when I pass an `ls` output to cp such as: cp `ls  ./**/**/*con_0001*` /Users/lo/Desktop/untitledfolder